# How could list decode to 'UTF-8'

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I got a list = [0x97, 0x52], not unicode object.  this is unicode of a charactor '青'(u'\u9752'). How could I change this list to unicode object first, then encode to 'UTF-8'?

Answer (score 2):

```
bytes = [0x97, 0x52]

code = bytes[0] * 256 + bytes[1]  # build the 16-bit code
char = unichr(code)               # convert code to unicode
utf8 = char.encode('utf-8')       # encode unicode as utf-8
print utf8                        # prints '青'
```

Comment: +1. Or, on one line: `print unichr(bytes[0]*256+bytes[1]).encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most elegant way, but it works for this particular example.

```
>>> ''.join([chr(x) for x in [0x97, 0x52]]).decode('utf-16be')
u'\u9752'
```